# how do i verify multiple occourences using threadname.expect with pexpect library

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, pexpect

```
self.nanokdp_p.sendline(cmd)
if self.nanokdp_p.expect(match, timeout = timeout)==0:
    print ("Device Sleep")
```

Right now i run a command on an interactive output using `self.nanokdp_p.sendline(cmd)`

Now i want to expect occourance of "match" string but dont want to stop at first occourence, instead i want expect or some custom function to run for a particular time and count occourances of match.

Also, this thing works if i just look and stop for first occourance.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.thread = pexpect.spawn(cmd, logfile = my_log_file, maxread = 1)



def expectMultipleOccurrencesOfanExp(thread, expToExpect, count, timeout=120, wait = 5):
        count += 1 # to match prints
        for i in range(1, count):
            if thread.expect(expToExpect, timeout)==0:
                if i == count:
                    return True
                elif i < count:
                    print (expToExpect + " found for " + str(i) + "th time")
                    time.sleep(wait)
                    continue
            return False
```

Comment: fyi, `pexpect.spawn()` creates a child *process*, not a *thread*.  In general, the difference may be essential.